# Inject HTML signature into Gmail from hosted page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, code-injection

I have the basic shell of a Chrome extension done and have come to the point where I am trying to inject an HTML signature into Gmail using code hosted on an unindexed page on my site.  The reason I want to do this is to be able to include web fonts, something that for the life me I can't figure out why Gmail hasn't allowed you to do from their font library.

In any regard, as I said, I have a right-click context menu option ready to trigger a script from my js function page and the extension loads without errors.  I need to figure out the best way to inject the HTML into the email and without losing any of the formatting that has been done on the page.

I have created the extension manifest, set the permissions on the context menu and created a function to call back to the js page that will inject the signature.

```
var contextMenus = {};

contextMenus.createSignature = 
    chrome.contextMenus.create(
        {"title": "Inject Signature",
        "contexts": ["editable"]},
            function (){
                if(chrome.runtime.lastError){
                    console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                }
            }
        );      

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(contextMenuHandler);

function contextMenuHandler(info, tab){
    if(info.menuItemId===contextMenus.createSignature){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            file: 'js/signature.js'
        });
    }
}
```

The end result is nothing enters the page and get massive errors related to cross-site because the domain is not the same obviously.  This has obviously been solved as there are numerous signature extensions out there.  I would probably use one of theirs but a) I want to build it on my own, b) they all want you to use their templates, none of them that I have seen will let you just use your own code.

So, any ideas?

Comment: The code you've shown is fine, it isn't where the error is generated. I guess there's something wrong in your signature.js. Also, you can inspect and debug those other extensions in devtools or in an IDE.

Comment: Right, the context and everything works fine, I'm just a bit lost as to the logic that actually inserts the code to the email.

Comment: I've added some simple JS to the signature.js to serve as a test that it's working:


var worker = {
  name: "John Doe",
  title: "Realtor",  
  email: "johndoe@example.com",
  signature: function(){
   return this.name + " " + this.title + " " + this.email;
  }
 }

 worker.signature();


When this is executed by right-clicking in a new Gmail message, I see these errors in the console: 

Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. I also receive another error relating to preload request and response